# combine equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I'm trying to add the moving average equation, but keep getting errors saying: 1. missing $ inserted
2. runaway argument?
3. missing }
4. undefined control sequence
despite the error my equation does show up, but give me me alot of errors in the log

```
\centering \overline{P}SM= \frac{PM + PM-1 + ...+PM -(n-1)} {{n}\frac{n}}
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} PM-i
\end{equation} \label{Movingavg
```

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: try inserting the `\overline.......}` inside `$...$` if you prefer inline math, or encapsulate it within `\[...\]` if you prefer display styled equation. And, you can remove the `\centering` before the math, if you would prefer the display style. Also, next time please post a `MWE`. The errors are because of the fact that you are using math outside it's designated environments. And, remove the `\frac{n}` or add the denominator part of fraction `\frac{num}{den}`.

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this:

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
\overline{p}_\text{SM} &= \frac {p_M + p_{M-1} + \cdots + p_{M-(n-1)}}{n}\\
                       &= \frac 1n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} p_{M-i}
\end{aligned}
\]
```

> [image]

Notes:

- the `SM` is an abbrev. for **simple moving** average, so it is better written in text mode
- all subscripts `_M` through `_{M-i}` are written using the underscore `_` they are not multiplied by `p`
- the two lines can be aligned at `=` and combined using the `aligned` construct
- the `\frac{1}{n}` can be reduced as `\frac1n`
- as a final note, you may want to lower the subscripts a bit more to be clear, this can be easily done by adding an extra empty `^{}` like this:
  `p_M^{} + p_{M-1}^{} + \cdots + ...`, etc., which would output:

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want, per chance?

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\overline{\!P}SM= \frac{PM + PM-1 + ...+PM -(n-1)} {n} \\
\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} PM-i
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]